# Distance matrix

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I am trying to determine the distance between everypoint in one data set vs the other data set in R.  Each data set has an X and Y parameter.  I have been converting the data sets into data frames and the finding the distance.  However my current code creates a large matrix to due this listing both the data sets as columns and rows. I then need to identify a specific part of the matrix I care about to get my answers, Is there a way just to put DSA as the columns and DSB as the rows.  this whould cut the matrix in 1/4 which since my data sets contain thousands of points each whould really cut down the time for the algorithum to run

Here is the code I am using

```
tumor<-data.frame(DSA[,c ("X_Parameter","Y_Parameter")])
cells<-data.frame(DSB[,c ("X_Parameter","Y_Parameter")])
distances<-as.matrix(dist(rbind(tumor,cells)))
row.start<-nrow(tumor)+1
row.end<-nrow(tumor)+nrow(cells)
col.start<-1
col.end<-nrow(tumor)
distances[row.start:row.end, col.start:col.end]
d<- distances[row.start:row.end, col.start:col.end]
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (simulated values are nice), the code you've tried and what the desired result should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Try `flexclust::dist2`:

```
n_tumor = 2000
n_cells = 2000
tumor = matrix(runif(n_tumor * 2), n_tumor, )
cells = matrix(runif(n_cells * 2), n_cells, )

t_dist = system.time({
  distances<-as.matrix(dist(rbind(tumor,cells)))
  row.start<-nrow(tumor)+1
  row.end<-nrow(tumor)+nrow(cells)
  col.start<-1
  col.end<-nrow(tumor)
  d <- distances[row.start:row.end, col.start:col.end]
})[3]

require(flexclust)
t_dist2 = system.time({d2 = dist2(x = cells, y = tumor, method = "euclidean")})[3]

t_dist # 1.477
t_dist2 # 0.244
identical(unname(d), d2) # TRUE
```

**EDIT:**
Another alternative is `proxy::dist`.

Answer (score 0):

This will compute only the portion of the matrix you need:

```
tumoridx <- rep(1:nrow(tumor), each=nrow(cells)
cellsidx <- rep(1:nrow(cells), nrow(tumor))
tcdist <- matrix(sqrt(rowSums((tumor[tumoridx, ] - cells[cellsidx, ])^2)),
     nrow(cells), nrow(tumor))
```